# How does one redraw an object for an animation in svg on loop?

Tags: animation, svg

I'm new to using SVG and I'm trying to create 3 circles that expand from the center of the screen one after the other on a loop. My problem is that when the loop occurs, since the first circle has had something drawn on top of it, it is hidden behind the other circles.

Here is the existing code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="470px" height="250px" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">

    <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(1,1)">
       <g transform-origin = "center" transform="scale(0,0)">
           <animateTransform id = "anim1" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
               from="0,0" to="1,1"
               begin="0s; anim3.end" dur="2.5s" fill="freeze"/>
           <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="red"/>
       </g>
       <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(0,0)">
            <animateTransform id = "anim2" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
                from="0,0" to="1,1"
                begin="anim1.end" dur="2.5s" fill="freeze"/>
            <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="blue"/>
        </g>
        <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(0,0)">
            <animateTransform id = "anim3" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
                from="0,0" to="1,1"
                begin="anim2.end" dur="2.5s" fill="freeze"/>
            <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="green"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

As it stands, it animates properly once, then the last circle redraws every few seconds since the other animations are hidden. I'd like it to relayer the circles on top for each loop. Since SVG doesn't support layers, it would seem to me that the easiest way to have the first circle appear again would be to redraw it on top, but I'm not sure how to do that and am having great difficulty figuring that out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the @Alexandr_T answer, and I'm adding a background `<rect>` that changes color with `<set>`. I hope this is the effect you were looking for.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="470" height="250" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
  
  <rect width="470" height="250" fill="green" >
     <set begin="anim1.begin" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill" to="green"></set>
     <set begin="anim2.begin" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill" to="red"></set>
     <set begin="anim3.begin" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill" to="blue"></set>
  </rect>

    <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(1,1)">
       <g transform-origin = "center" transform="scale(0,0)">
           <animateTransform id = "anim1" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
               from="0,0" to="1,1"
               begin="0s; anim3.end" dur="2.5s" />
           <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="red"/>
       </g>
       <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(0,0)">
            <animateTransform id = "anim2" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
                from="0,0" to="1,1"
                begin="anim1.end" dur="2.5s" />
            <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="blue"/>
        </g>
        <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(0,0)">
            <animateTransform id = "anim3" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
                from="0,0" to="1,1"
                begin="anim2.end" dur="2.5s" />
            <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="green"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Beautiful decision I also thought about such a decision. But first I decided to search if any other svg properties

Comment: Almost perfect, thank you. I used your answer, but had the background change at begin -.01 to get rid of the slight stutter after each circle. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just remove `fill =" freeze "`

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="470px" height="250px" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">

    <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(1,1)">
       <g transform-origin = "center" transform="scale(0,0)">
           <animateTransform id = "anim1" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
               from="0,0" to="1,1"
               begin="0s; anim3.end" dur="2.5s" />
           <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="red"/>
       </g>
       <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(0,0)">
            <animateTransform id = "anim2" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
                from="0,0" to="1,1"
                begin="anim1.end" dur="2.5s" />
            <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="blue"/>
        </g>
        <g transform-origin="center" transform="scale(0,0)">
            <animateTransform id = "anim3" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
                from="0,0" to="1,1"
                begin="anim2.end" dur="2.5s" />
            <circle cx="235" cy="125" r="275" fill="green"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That kinda works, but what I want specifically is to have the green explode out of the blue, the red explode out of the green, the blue to explode out of the red on repeat. So the previous colors stay around as the new background. This new code will reset the background to white each time. Like I said, the first iteration of the loop is precisely what I want, I just want it to continue instead of breaking.

Ultimately, it's not all that important at this point, I'm just kinda curious as to how one might do it more than anything.

Comment: @Myrnedraith I understand you. I will continue to look for a solution. Thank you for the interesting question.